# var i = [0] in a for loop, then incremented i++ - why does it work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, type-conversion

In a book that I'm reading (JavaScript & JQuery - Interactive Front End Development by Jon Duckett) there's an interesting error or (at least I think so) which doesn't stop the code from working:

```
for (var i = [0]; i < options.length; i++) {         
   addEvent(options[i], 'click', radioChanged);       
}
```

This is a part of script that loops through all radio buttons in a form and attaches an event listener (it doesn't really matter what it does).

But...

1. Why is i initialised as an array at all?
2. Why does the incrementation work?
3. Why does the whole loop work?

Of course if you replace var i = [0] with var i = 0 the code still works.

When you add some alerts to check the value of i in each iteration of the loop and the type of i, at the second iteration type of i changes from object (after all in the first iteration it is an array) to number.
That's a kind of implicit type conversion I have never come across so far (and google don't help much). Can anyone explain what's going on under the hood?

```
for (var i = [0]; i < options.length; i++) {         
   addEvent(options[i], 'click', radioChanged);  
   alert(i); // --> 1   2   3 ...
   alert(type of i); // --> object   number   number ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The spec [says (§ 11.3.1)](http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1) that the `++` operator converts its operand to a number before incrementing:

> 3. Let *oldValue* be `ToNumber`(`GetValue`(*lhs*)).

When called on an object, the `GetValue` internal operation will call `toString()`, which, for an array, will join its elements, returning `'0'`.

Comment: @Tadek: It's more of a confusing feature.  The spec says this so that incrementing `'1'` would result in `2` rather than `'11'`.